# What does "toutes les eaux" mean?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

I read a fairy tale in French called "La belle au bois dormant" (yeah, that one) and the second sentence reveals this turn of speech:

> Ils allèrent à **toutes les eaux** du monde ; vœux, pèlerinages, menues dévotions, tout fut mis en œuvre, et rien n’y faisait.

I wonder what is the meaning of the selection? Is there the same saying in English?

Comment: Maybe similar to "the seven seas"?

Comment: Eaux d'un navire. Trace qu'il laisse derrière lui à mesure qu'il avance. Synon. sillage.Prendre, suivre, se mettre dans, se tenir dans les eaux (d'un bâtiment). Entrer ou gouverner dans son sillage.cnrtl.fr/definition/eaux – follow all trails [as in wake of a boat]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the religious vocabulary that follows (*vœux*, *pèlerinages*, *dévotions*), *eaux* might have been a metonymy for *eaux bénites* ([holy waters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holy_water).)

They went to many churches and pilgrimage places to implore God about their wish to have a baby.

However, all occurrences of *aller aux eaux* from Perrault century authors have a different meaning, precisely described by None in [her answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/48505/1109) so **that should definitely be the accepted one.**

e.g. from de Vergoncey, *Le pèlerin véritable de la Terre Sainte*, 1615

[image]

> *[...], et imiter les médecins qui ordonnent d'aller aux eaux à ceux de qui le mal ne peut être surmonté par leur remèdes.*

> [...], and imitate the physicians who order to go to the waters to those whose illness cannot be overcome by their medicines.

Comment: @onkeltem You should accept the [other answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/48505/1109). Mine was incorrect speculation and she set me straight.

Answer (score 7):

Without rejecting @jlliagre interpretation, which I find convincing, I must say I never understood that sentence that way. I've always understood *les eaux* in Perrault's text in its medicinal meaning. *Eaux* as in *villes d'eaux*, the English "spa", the German *Medizinische Bäder*.

In Charles Perrault's times (17th century) *aller aux eaux* or *prendre les eaux* meant *aller faire une cure thermale*.

These are not much used nowadays, or used between brackets<sup>1</sup>, but we can still find the phrase in dictionaries.

> ***Les eaux*** : les eaux minérales d'une station thermale. *Aller aux eaux*, *prendre les eaux*, faire une cure thermale. *Une ville d'eaux*. ([Le Robert](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/eau))

Although English prefers the word "spa", when translating a text from French, "[take the waters](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/take_the_waters)" is a common translation.

> I was first going to the Pyrenees, to take the waters of Cauterets; ([The Memoirs of Chateaubriand](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/55070/55070-h/55070-h.htm)).

The sentence in the question is [the exact wording](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k6566866f/f2.item.r=la%20belle%20au%20bois%20dormant%20la%20belle%20au%20bois%20dormant)<sup>2</sup> of Perrault's, not an adaptation. The translations into foreign languages are often very loose, but when translations stick to Perrault's text, the medicinal interpretation is retained - at least for those I know.

> They went to all the waters in the world; vows, pilgrimages, all ways were tried and all to no purpose. ([18th century translation](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/29021/pg29021-images.html#The_Sleeping_Beauty_in_the_Wood) by  Robert Samber and J. E. Mansion)

> Sie reisten in alle Bäder der Welt, legten Gelübde ab, machten Wallfahrten. ([1921th century translation](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/42900/pg42900-images.html#Dornroschen) by Hans Krause)

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>[Quand on « allait aux eaux » à Vichy](https://fr.anecdotrip.com/quand-on-allait-aux-eaux-a-vichy-un-traitement-de-cheval-par-vinaigrette).</sup>
<sup><sup>2</sup> But the punctuation has not been reproduced correctly. The original text has a semi-colon in place of a colon.</sup>

Comment: Ma spéculation est tombée à l'eau ;-)

Comment: @jlliagre LOL... et malgré ta mention de la réponse à accepter - t'a encore eu 2 votes depuis ma réponse, et moi 1 seul ! (snif) Je rigole ;-), je sais déjà que certains votent n'importe comment, + 8 pour une réponse qui m'a pris 1 min à rédiger (une/la) et d'autres réponses qui prennent bcp + de temps sont quasiment ignorée.

Comment: Et ça continue... Ces votes sont peut-être motivés par des *Se non è vero, è molto ben trovato* ou alors, on salue mon fair play... Les *voix* des voteurs sont impénétrables ;-)

Comment: How can eaux refer to spas here? The rest of the sentence is about religious endeavors.

Comment: @Lambie *Aller aux eaux/ prendre les eaux*  means « to go to the waters ».  I am not imposing my understanding on anyone. You don't like it, the OP doesn't like it, no big deal. As you noticed when you checked with the original text the OP made a mistake when reproducing the punctuation, I won't tell you the difference between a colon and a semi colon, I'm sure you know it, so I'm astonished when you say the rest of the sentence is about "religious endeavors" (your words).

Comment: @Lambie A semi colon separates two independent clauses related in thought. To my mind the relation in thought is obviously not religion, but trying to get a baby. They tried medicine and they tried religion. You're free to understand it differently.

Comment: @Lambie 1. ***Aller aux eaux**: Aller prendre les eaux médicinales pour sa santé.* Pierre Danet, *Nouveau dictionnaire françois et latin*, 1683. 2. *Motifs qui déterminent à aller aux Eaux , diversité d'opinions sur les Eaux Minérales . Supériorité de celles de Spa , Agrémens du Lieu .*, Jean-Philippe de Limbourg, *Les amusemens de SPA*, 1782.

Comment: @jlliagre I know that. How could I have said spa if I didn't know that?? The old-fashioned expression is: "to take the waters". Take the waters. Punctuation is a matter of perception. In literature, it can vary a great deal. The rest of the sentence **after the semi colon** is about religious endeavors: vows (to Jesus or Mary), pilgrimages and small devotions. And I don't think aller a tous les eaux refers to spas. **If it is about having a baby, then yes, taking the waters would be right** as in visiting many spas. I did not read the whole story.  So would the religious part.

Comment: @Lambie I believe the reasons I was mistaken is the text as initially written used a colon, so the religious matter would have been an explanation of *aller aux eaux*. I didn't do any research (another mistake) and just use logical reasoning. With a semicolon, there is no such relationship. The expression is well documented and it would have been more than implausible that a specific different meaning had appeared in that single book and no other before or after.

Comment: Exactly, it is an explanation, a result. There is a relationship; the relationship is there. Otherwise, there would be a period (full stop as the Brits say).

Comment: @Lambie Non, c'est le deux-points qui introduit une explication. Un point-virgule sert de séparation et indique ici une séquence ou une concurrence. Pour tenter de résoudre son problème, le couple a essayé une approché médicale **puis** ou **aussi** une approche  spirituelle. On peut très bien remplacer un point virgule par un point mais on ne peut pas remplacer un deux-points par un point.

Comment: @jlliagre Come on, La belle aux bois dormant?? Solution médicale?? Paru en 1697. Je disais que le truc religieux/spirituel y est. Oui, des efforts spirituels ou religieux. Pourquoi ne me dis-tu pas la bonne ponctuation au lieu de me **citer** des régles? Que cela soit deux-points ou point virgule, le reste de la phrase **parle de** (ha ha)*spiritual endeavors*.

Comment: @Lambie Tu penses qu'il n'y avait pas de médecins au XVIIe siècle ?

Comment: @Lambie et ce n'est pas **le reste de la phrase**, un point-virgule sépare deux phrases **distinctes**, simplement juxtaposées.

Comment: @None Je dis que "pèlerinages, menues dévotions, tout fut mis en œuvre, et rien n’y faisait" sont des "spiritual devotions" Et j'ai raison.

Comment: @Lambie La question n'est pas de savoir ce que sont les actions que tu cites. Bien sûr que ce sont des *spritual* quelque chose. Tout le monde est d'accord là dessus, c'est écrit noir sur blanc.

Comment: @Lambie "If it is about having a baby, then yes, taking the waters would be right as in visiting many spas. I did not read the whole story. So would the religious part.". The very [first sentence](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/La_Belle_au_bois_dormant) settles it then: "Il estoit une fois un Roi & une Reine qui estoient si faschez de n’avoir point d’enfans, si faschez qu’on ne sçauroit dire." (Perrault).

Comment: @EylaChu-Generis Yep, it would have been much clearer then.